# What is wrong with my signal handling?

Tags: django, django-models

I have this:

```
class PersonneRelation(models.Model):
    #blabla
    pass


@receiver(post_save, sender=PersonneRelation)
def signal_receiver(sender, **kwargs):
    print('***'*5)
    print(sender)
```

This works well... until I add another receiver like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=PersonneTravel)
def signal_receiver(sender, **kwargs):
    created = kwargs['created']
    obj = kwargs['instance']
    print('***'*5)
    print(sender)
    print(created)
```

It's not the same sender, so it should differentiate those two signals... but as soon as I add the previous signal, it seems to override the first one, and the first one is never called anymore. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you defined both with the same method name?.. (in the same file?)

Comment: ...it was the problem. May I ask you to answer so I can check your answer as valid? Any newbie with signals like me should be warned about "one different name for each signal handling"...

Comment: Olivier Pons, I don't have a quote at the minute for this but python stores all objects as dictionaries and I'm fairly sure that includes methods too, hence if you redefine it with the same name it will overwrite the key

Comment: I'm used to C where you just can define only one function with the same name in the same file. Same with C++. Same with Java. Same with LUA. Same with Delphi. Same with ADA. Same with all "clean" languages. It's a weird behavior and should not be allowed IMHO.

Comment: Thats the joy of compiled languages vs interpreted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined two methods with the same name and essentially you can't do that in python within the same py file.

I prefer to initialise my signals as follows since its more explicit what they'll do but as long as you give them separate method names you'll be ok

```
post_save.connect(do_something_with_travel, sender=PersonneTravel)
def do_something_with_travel(sender, **kwargs):
    created = kwargs['created']
    obj = kwargs['instance']
    print('***'*5)
    print(sender)
    print(created)
```

Comment: Note: either syntax is perfectly valid (I just wanted to pad my answer a bit more than one sentence!)